# linking to a shared folder in firefox

Tags: c#, html, firefox

i have an asp hyperlink i want to link it to a .doc file found on a shared folder.
i was able to do this in internet explorer but not in firefox:
my code:

```
hlc.NavigateUrl = @"file:\\direct\upload\file.doc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Might want to use forwardslashes (as per convention)

```
hlc.NavigateUrl = @"file:///direct/upload/file.doc";
```